# run two cron jobs on alternate minutes

Tags: php, cron

I currently have a cron job running every minute on my server, and I can do that without problem:

```
* * * * *
```

But how would I run two different files on alternate minutes?

So file '1.php' on even minutes, and '2.php' on odd minutes?

so...

```
00:00 - run 1.php
00:01 - run 2.php
00:02 - run 1.php
00:03 - run 2.php
00:04 - run 1.php
```

etc!

Answer (score 0):

Just check the current minute in PHP like this:

1.php

```
if (date('i') % 2 == 0) {
    // run task here
}
```

2.php

```
if (date('i') % 2 != 0) {
    // run task here
}
```